# From Pandas Dataframe find unique values in column and see if those values have the same values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get all unique values from one column, and see if each unique value have the same values in another column. below I have a data frame and I am looking for unique values in the first column `{2,3,4}`. And I am trying to see if these values have unique values in same position in the last column.

By looking, clearly only `3` values in the first column has only the same values (`4`) in corresponding position in the last column .  So `(3, 4)` matches. How could I achieve this paring `(3, 4)` in `Pandas`? Unique values in column 1 must only have unique values in column 4!

```
2  2  1  4
2  3  4  4
3  4  3  4
3  5  8  4
2  6  9  2
4  1  6  2
4  4  1  4 
2  4  5  2
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: you define r(a) to be the set of rows whose value in the 1st column is a. If they all have the same value (say b) in the fourth column, then you return the pair (a, b)? If there are many such pairs, you return the list [(a1, b1), (a2, b2), …] Is this correct?

Comment: @IgorRivin Exactly! You could not have said it better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not quit clear the question , since column1 have match 2 and 4 with column 4 . thanks Igor's comment.

```
df.groupby('c1').c4.unique().loc[lambda x : x.str.len()==1].str[0]
Out[116]: 
c1
3    4
Name: c4, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I will clear that up. The thing is that, unique values in column 1 must only have unique values in column 4. 2 matches with 4, but aslo matches with 2.